# Can I pass multiple checkbox checked with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Here is the script (javascript & jQuery) :

```js
$('#button_submit').click(function() {
    var check = { 'opt[]' : []};
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        check['opt[]'].push($(this).val());
    });
}
```

and the html one :

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h4>Data Options</h4>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type='checkbox' name='opt[]' value='1'id='ck1' /> Counts<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='opt[]' value='2'id='ck2' /> Male<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='opt[]' value='3'id='ck3' /> Female<br>
        <input type="button" id="button_submit" value="go">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Im not getting the checked checkboxes, is anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the markup above this is how I would populate check

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_submit').click(function() {
       var check = { 'opt[]' : []};
       $('input[name="opt[]"]:checked').each(function() {
           check['opt[]'].push($(this).val());
       });

       // just for a bit of debugging
       for(var x in check['opt[]']) {
           $('span').append(check['opt[]'][x]);
       }
       // assuming you want to do something other than just let it submit

       return false;      
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8Dm9C/1/ for an example

Answer (score 2):

try to add `$(document).ready`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button_submit').click(function() 
  {...}
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check multiple checkboxes

```
$("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true )
```